# How can I find where a symbol used in `derive` is defined?

Tags: rust

I come from a Java background, in which finding a symbol definition location is straightforward: it's ether in the same package or it comes via the imports.

Here `Deserialize` is defined in the `serde` crate, yet the source file contains no references to `serde` crate:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Args {
    arg_spec: Vec<String>,
    flag_short: bool,
    flag_porcelain: bool,
    flag_branch: bool,
    flag_z: bool,
    flag_ignored: bool,
    flag_untracked_files: Option<String>,
    flag_ignore_submodules: Option<String>,
    flag_git_dir: Option<String>,
    flag_repeat: bool,
    flag_list_submodules: bool,
}
```

([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/blob/718799c265d4e6fea635906cb57379a441021f3c/examples/status.rs#L27))

Comment: `Deserialize` is a macro, and that's just how they work. It is imported by: `#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;` (lines 19-20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the declaration:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
```

([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/blob/718799c265d4e6fea635906cb57379a441021f3c/examples/status.rs#L19-L20))

This brings *all* the macros defined in the `serde_derive` crate into scope. One of those is the `Deserialize` *macro* which helps implement the `Deserialize` trait.

This was the old way of doing things. In the 2018 edition, the [preferred way is to import macros with the more familiar  `use` statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/macros/macro-changes.html).

Comment: Thank you, using `use` statement makes lot of since. 

I was thrown off by `Deserialize` being a trait not a macro, so I though `#[macro_use]` has noting to do with it. But apparently `#[derive(Deserialize)]` needs the  `#[proc_macro_derive(Deserialize, attributes(serde))]` macro, not the trait itself.